# manipulating image z-index with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, z-index

I have a row of 160x160px floated images resized to 100x100px by the browser.

On hover, the images animate to their usual size and margins are manipulated to keep them in the same place.

What I want to achieve next is to have the enlarged image move to the front, then back again after the hover event. I'm try to achieve this by adding and removing a class where z-index is 100.

The HTML is:

```
    <div id="content_top">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="images/thumbs/thumb1.jpg" width="100"  height="100" border="0" alt=""/>
        <img class="thumbnail" src="images/thumbs/thumb2.jpg" width="100" height="100" border="0" alt=""/>
        <img class="thumbnail" src="images/thumbs/thumb3.jpg" width="100" height="100" border="0" alt=""/>
        <img class="thumbnail" src="images/thumbs/thumb4.jpg" width="100" height="100" border="0" alt=""/>
        <img class="thumbnail" src="images/thumbs/thumb5.jpg" width="100" height="100" border="0" alt=""/>
    </div>
```

With the CSS:

```
#content_top {
      height: 210px;
}

#content_top img{
      float:left;
      padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    }

    .ontop {
      z-index: 100;
    }
```

The jQuery I'm using is:

```
$('#content_top img').hover(function(){
    $(this).filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
        'width' : '160px',
        'height' : '160px',
        'marginLeft' : '-30px',
        'marginRight' : '-30px',
        'marginBottom' : '-30px'
        }, 'fast', 'linear'
    ).addClass('ontop');
}, function(){
    $(this).animate({
        'width' : '100px',
        'height' : '100px',
        'marginLeft' : '0px',
        'marginRight' : '0px',
        'marginBottom' : '0px'
    }, 'fast', 'linear'
    ).removeClass('ontop');
});
```

All works fine, except the z-index part. I've tested that the class is being added, and it is. Tried various ways of positioning the images, even wrapping them in container divs and changing the z-index of those.

What have I missed?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried to set the position (in CSS) to absolute?

Comment: I find `z-index` changes do not repaint automatically in all situations.  It's a common problem when using jQuery UI's `draggable` system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The z-index property works only on positioned elements.

Try this...

```
#content_top img{
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    float:left;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}

#content_top img.ontop {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Here is a working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Wgy3E/1/

Comment: Superb. I'd always thought float and position:relative were mutually exclusive. Also learned that I needed to to use "#content_top img.ontop" rather than just ".ontop" which wasn't working. jsFiddle will come in handy, too. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. `#content_top img` is more specifc as only `.ontop`. To learn more about css specifity take a look: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 2):

> z-index only works on positioned
>   elements (position:absolute,
>   position:relative, or position:fixed). [[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_z-index.asp)]

Answer (score 0):

does defining a lower z-index in the img work? else try to use the jquery .setStyle({z-index: ''}); to a lower value instead of removing the class.